# Html Agility Pack c# Paragraph parsing problem

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am having a couple of issues with my code, I am trying to pull every paragraph from a page, but at the moment it is only selecting the last paragraph.

here is my code.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='body']/p"))
{
  string text = node.InnerText;
  lblTest2.Text = text;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop you are taking the current node innerText and assigning it to the label. You do this to *each* node, so of course you only see the last one - you are not preserving the previous ones.

Try this:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='body']/p"))
{
  string text = node.InnerText;
  lblTest2.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Has this changed? doc (assuming this is from a declaration like "HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();" doesn't work for me; specifically, it has no "DocumentNode" member...? This is with a brand new NuGet of HtmlAgilityPack (version 1.4.6.0)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument.cs <-- it certainly looks like it is there.

Comment: Thanks; the problem was that "using HtmlDocument = System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument;" somehow got added to my using clause, and that generic version of HtmlDocument was being used; I had to explicitly specify "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument" for the right class to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, XPath is no fun.  I'd recommend using LINQ syntax instead:

```
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode
    .DescendantNodes()
    .Single(x => x.Id == "body")
    .DescendantNodes()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "p")) 
{
    string text = node.InnerText;
    lblTest2.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: took me a while to figure it out. Look at what he is doing _in_ the loop.