# Why is this HtmlAgilityPack operation invalid when there are, indeed, matching elements?

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I get "InvalidOperationException > Message=Sequence contains no matching element" with the following code:

```
private void buttonLoadHTML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetParagraphsListFromHtml(@"C:\PlatypiRUs\fitt.html");
}

// This code adapted from Kirk Woll's answer at 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752840/html-agility-pack-c-sharp-paragraph-
   parsing-problem
public List<string> GetParagraphsListFromHtml(string sourceHtml)
{
    var pars = new List<string>();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(sourceHtml);
    foreach (var par in doc.DocumentNode
        .DescendantNodes()
        .Single(x => x.Id == "body")
        .DescendantNodes()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "p"))
        //.Where(x => x.Name == "h1" || x.Name == "h2" || x.Name == "h3" || x.Name 
           == "hp" || )) <-- This is what I'd really like to do, but I don't know if   
           this is possible or, if it is, if the syntax is correct
    {
        pars.Add(par.InnerText);
    }
    // test
    foreach (string s in pars)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
    return pars;
}
```

Why is the code not finding the paragraphs?

I really want to find *all* the text (h1..3 or higher vals, too), but this is a start.

BTW: The html file I'm testing with *does* have some paragraph elements.

### UPDATE

In response to Amy's implied request, and in the interest of full disclosure/ultimate illumination, here is the entire test html file:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: orange;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: Blue;   
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    color: white;    
    font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Palatino', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<h1>Found in the Translation</h1>
<h2>Bilingual Editions of Classic Literature</h2>
<div><label>Contact: </label><a href="mailto:axx3andspace@gmail.com">Found in the Translation</a></div>

<h2><cite>Around the World in 80 Days</cite> by Jules Verne (French &amp; English Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Paperback</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1495308081" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51BCZUX2-dL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Kindle</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I0DOYRE" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51BCZUX2-dL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>

<h2><cite>Gulliver's Travels</cite> by Jonathan Swift (English &amp; French Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Paperback</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1495374688" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/517O76OyaWL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Kindle</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I5319ZO" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/517O76OyaWL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>

<h2><cite>Journey to the Center of the Earth</cite> by Jules Verne (French &amp; English Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Paperback</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1495409031" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41hosXOIw8L._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Kindle</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I6LG25M" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41qj8DfrihL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>

<h2><cite>Treasure Island</cite> by Robert Louis Stevenson (English &amp; Finnish Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Paperback</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1495418936" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51veMV3OiOL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Kindle</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IA5V4KC" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51XNUWbA07L._SL160_.jpg" /></a>

<h2><cite>Robinson Crusoe</cite> by Daniel Defoe (English &amp; French Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Paperback</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1495448053" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51QQMRPrP9L._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Kindle</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I9IE8OY" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5128hqiw3DL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>

<h2><cite>Don Quixote</cite> by Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra (Spanish &amp; English Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Paperback</h3></br>
<h3>Volume I</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149474967X" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51HqjOPXLVL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Volume II</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1494803445" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51NONygEMYL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Volume III</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1494841983" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G%2BW3ICHkL._SL160_.jpg" /></a></br>
<h3>Kindle</h3></br>
<h3>Volume I</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HQMWPQ2" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51HqjOPXLVL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Volume II</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HYN2QGM" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51NONygEMYL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Volume III</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HLX519E" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G%2BW3ICHkL._SL160_.jpg" /></a></br>

<h2><cite>Alice's Adventures in Wonderland</cite> by Lewis Carroll (English &amp; German Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Coming soon; for now, see:</h3></br/>
<h3>Paperback</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193659420X" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5143vIpQ2YL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Kindle</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ESLTIYQ" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BX0Dy7uNL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>

<h2><cite>Alice's Adventures in Wonderland</cite> by Lewis Carroll (English &amp; Italian Side by Side)</h2>
<h3>Coming soon; for now, see:</h3></br/>
<h3>Paperback</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193659420X" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/5143vIpQ2YL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Kindle</h3>
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ESLTIYQ" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BX0Dy7uNL._SL160_.jpg" /></a>

<h2>Other Sites:</h2>
<p><a href="http://usamaporama.azurewebsites.net/"  target="_blank">USA Map-O-Rama</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/"  target="_blank">Award-winning Movies, Books, and Music</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.bigsurgarrapata.com/"  target="_blank">Garrapata State Park in Big Sur Throughout the Seasons</a></p>
```

### UPDATE 2

This works (although it is with "live" web pages, and not html files saved to disk):

```
public List<string> GetParagraphsListFromHtml(string sourceHtml)
{
    var pars = new List<string>();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(sourceHtml);

    var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = getHtmlWeb.Load("http://www.montereycountyweekly.com/opinion/letters/article_e333a222-942d-11e3-ba9c-001a4bcf6878.html"); 
    //http://www.bigsurgarrapata.com/ only returned one paragraph
    // http://usamaporama.azurewebsites.net/ <-- none
    // http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/ <- same as bigsurgarrapata
    var pTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
    int counter = 1;
    if (pTags != null)
    {
        foreach (var pTag in pTags)
        {
            pars.Add(pTag.InnerText);
            MessageBox.Show(pTag.InnerText);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("done!");
    return pars;
}
```

Comment: It might help if we see the HTML you're parsing.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it as an update - it's not too voluminous.

Comment: `This works (although it is with "live" web pages, and not html files saved to disk):` Are you sure you know what you are doing? In your last edit, you load the string (*sourceHtml*) to `doc` but then not use it and load the html from an url.

Comment: @L.B: Yes, I realize there is an unused arg in there; this code is in a state of flux, as I'm trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be pretty easy; this is not complete, but this, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack), is enough to get started:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// There are various options, set as needed
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

htmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Platypus\dplatypus.htm");

if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
{
    IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> textNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()");
    foreach (HtmlNode node in textNodes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```